# Trouble installing glibc-2.15

Tags: installation, makefile, glibc

I am trying to install `glibc-2.15` on my system over an existing `glibc-2.10.2`. The steps I followed are:
1. In the directory where the `glibc` sources are unpacked, created a directory `glibc-build`.
2. Ran `configure` from the `glibc-build` directory like so:
`./../glibc-2.15/configure --prefix=/usr`
3. Make to build the libraries, like so:
`make`
I get the following error on the compilation rule given below:

```
gcc ../sysdeps/i386/i686/fpu/e_logl.S -c  -D__NO_MATH_INLINES -D__LIBC_INTERNAL_MATH_INLINES -I../include -I/home/sriram/glibc/glibc-build/math -I/home/sriram/glibc/glibc-build -I../sysdeps/i386/elf -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/gnu -I../sysdeps/unix/common -I../sysdeps/unix/mman -I../sysdeps/unix/inet -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/posix -I../sysdeps/i386/i686/fpu -I../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/i386/i486 -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386/i486 -I../sysdeps/i386/fpu -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754 -I../sysdeps/generic/elf -I../sysdeps/generic -I../nptl  -I.. -I../libio -I.  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h   -DNOT_IN_libc=1 -DIS_IN_libm=1    -DASSEMBLER  -DGAS_SYNTAX -g -Wa,--noexecstack  -Wa,-mtune=i686 -o /home/sriram/glibc/glibc-build/math/e_logl.o -MD -MP -MF /home/sriram/glibc/glibc-build/math/e_logl.o.dt -MT /home/sriram/glibc/glibc-build/math/e_logl.o 
../sysdeps/i386/i686/fpu/e_logl.S: Assembler messages:
../sysdeps/i386/i686/fpu/e_logl.S:49: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `fcomip'
../sysdeps/i386/i686/fpu/e_logl.S:75: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `fcomip'
make[2]: *** [/home/sriram/glibc/glibc-build/math/e_logl.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sriram/glibc/glibc-2.15/math'
make[1]: *** [math/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sriram/glibc/glibc-2.15'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have looked over the Internet to find a solution but have not gotten anywhere. How do I get rid of this error??

Comment: What kind of system are you on? 32-bit, 64-bit? How old? Show us the output of 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' .